# posixct cannot read in time correctly

Tags: r, posixct

I'm having trouble with `PosiXct` in R. 
I have epoch timestamps in `GMT` and am trying to convert to `US/Eastern`.

When I convert from epoch to timestamp, and specify `tz = "GMT"`, R adds 4 fours to my time thinking I am converting from Eastern (where I am currently) to `GMT`.

```
> data$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct((data$TIMESTAMP/1000), origin="1970-01-01",tz = "GMT")
> str(data)
'data.frame':   1353717 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ TIMESTAMP                    : num  1.49e+12 1.49e+12 1.49e+12 1.49e+12 1.49e+12 ...
 $ Timestamp                    : POSIXct, format: "2017-04-01 04:00:33" "2017-04-01 04:00:33" "2017-04-01 04:01:15" "2017-04-01 04:01:15" ...
```

When I try to force `Timestamp` to be in `US/Eastern`, it converts it back to `GMT`. I'm really confused. Can anyone help?

```
> attr(data$Timestamp,"tzone") <- "US/Eastern"
> str(data)
'data.frame':   1353717 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ TIMESTAMP                    : num  1.49e+12 1.49e+12 1.49e+12 1.49e+12 1.49e+12 ...
 $ Timestamp                    : POSIXct, format: "2017-04-01 00:00:33" "2017-04-01 00:00:33" "2017-04-01 00:01:15" "2017-04-01 00:01:15" ...
```

The mix up is that R thinks the raw data is in `US/Eastern` (my current time zone), but it's really in `GMT`, and I'm trying to convert to `US/Eastern`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `lubridate`'s `force_tz` to force GMT and then used `format` to get it in `US/Eastern`. Wow that's more complicated/annoying than I would have thought.